# Inflating fragments inside ViewPager fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager that consists of a number of pages depending on a JSON response from a server. The design requires each page of the ViewPager to contain their own tabs. Nesting a ViewPager inside a ViewPager did not seem like a good idea and so I used a ViewSwitcher inside the individual pages instead (I only need two views max).

```
 <ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/VS_ContentFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FL_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FL_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</ViewSwitcher>
```

The layout of each page inside the ViewPager is shown above. All I'm trying to do now is to replace each of the FrameLayouts within this fragment with new fragments displaying the content of each of the tabs.

The problem is that when I replace a particular FrameLayout by a Fragment, it gets confused as to which FrameLayout to replace. What I observe is that there is only one page inside the ViewPager that always has the content. All other pages are empty. How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Where are you creating and committing the fragment transactions?

Comment: Inside the Fragment that is being generated as a part of the ViewPager. I have found a solution for it (which I have posted below). Not sure if that is the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are generating a hosting fragment per `ViewPager` page, and then applying the layout you include in your question to each of those fragments, then you should be able to achieve your goal using the child fragment manager. See [`Fragment.getChildFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) (I'm sure there's a support version too):

> Return a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments inside of this Fragment.

The restricted scope of this `FragmentManager` will allow it to uniquely identify the correct `FrameLayout`, even if your `ViewPager` itself contains multiple FrameLayouts with the same id.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, I did not know this. This is definitely the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I have implemented right now is to get a hold of the FrameLayout inside each fragment and to set its View ID dynamically by calling

```
View.GenerateViewId()
```

This way, the view IDs of each of the FrameLayouts are unique and the Fragments get replaced properly without any problems. Open to suggestions if there's a better way to do the same.